# How can I delete a specific river using NEST?

Tags: c#, .net, elasticsearch, nest

If `_client` is an `IElasticClient` instance, I can delete the `_river` index by doing the following:

```
_client.DeleteIndex(i => i.Index("_river"));
```

However, I want to keep some of my rivers intact. How can I delete a specific river?

Comment: Couldn't find an answer to this question in the search, so I'm posting one now that I've figured it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There does not appear to be an overload of `IElasticClient.Delete` or its variations that will allow you to delete a specific river.

However, you can achieve the same effect by issuing a DELETE request using the underlying `IConnection`, specifying the URL of the river:

```
var uri = new Uri("http://localhost:9200");
_client.Connection.Delete(new Uri(uri.ToUrlAndOverridePath("/_river/my_river")));
```